# How does the string populate an array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm creating a simple program to see how a string populates an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string1[100];
    int i;

    printf("Enter sentence.\n");
    fgets(string1, 100, stdin);

    for (i=0; i<=15; i++)
       puts(&string1[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm having a bit of a problem understanding how the string is populating an array. My expectation is that the string will be completely stored in string1[0] and any further indexes will come up blank. However, when I throw the loop to see if my assumption is true, it turns out that every index has been filled in by the string. Am I misunderstanding how the string is filling the array?

Comment: no, you only have one string of length 100. so your `puts` will issue a kind of shifted version of your sentence, or garbage if your sentence is shorter than 15 chars.

Comment: A string is several characters, `string1[0]` is a **single** character. How can it be stored there in its entirety?

Comment: Yes, you've misunderstood. C doesn't really have strings, it has arrays of chars with a null byte to terminate. Yu can manipulate the chars as small integers using the [] syntax,  and string[0] is the first letter, string[1] the second letters, and string[N] is nul.

Comment: @StoryTeller If I get rid of the for loop and use puts(&string1[0]); It will output the original sentence instead of just outputting the first character, which is causing me confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not `string1` layout per se but how `puts` interprets it. Strings are represented by `char` arrays in C while their end is marked as null terminator (character with code 0):

```
 S e n t e n c e \0
 ^         ^
 string1   &string1[5]
```

`&string1[5]` is a pointer to a one character, but since the following character is not null terminator, following memory is interpreted as a string and `nce` gets printed.

You'll need to use `putc` and access individual characters:

```
putc(string1[i])
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was misinterpreting the other answers, because I was misreading as if only one letter should have been outputted per loop based on their reasoning. However, showing the &string1[5] example help cement what was going on when I use puts.

Answer (score 2):

For the string "Hello!", the memory representation would be something like this

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  'H'  |  'e'  |  'l'  |  'l'  |  'o'  |  '!'  | '\0'  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The first cell, at index 0, contains the first character. And each subsequent character is contained in a cell with an increasing index.

Library functions like `puts` expect you to pass the address of the first character, and then they read the string up to `\0`.

So if you pass simply `string1` or `&string1[0]`, it will resolve to the address of `'H'`.

If you pass `&string[1]`, it will resolve to the address of `'e'`, and the library function will think *that* is the first character, because that's the contract C strings are designed with.

Answer (score 1):

***string is not stored in string1[0]*** but string's first character is stored at `string1[0]` or string starts at `(string1+0)`. Here, `&string1[0] or (string1+0)` can be seen as a pointer, a pointer to C String `string1`.

In that sense, every valid index `i` of `string1` will give you a valid pointer `(string1 + i)` which will point to some part of C String `string1`.

In the last for loop you are printing the suffixes of string `string1` which are pointed by `(string1 + 0), (string1 + 1), (string1 + 2)`...